# Excel (VBA) Exportar arquivo .XLSM para .CVS de um intervalo específico

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv, macro

Estou utilizando a macro abaixo para converter um arquivo .xlsm em .csv, mas ocorre que ele converte todo o conteúdo da planilha, mas preciso que seja convertido apenas um intervalo de dados, conforme vou tento mais informações sendo inserido na planilha.

Tentei acrescentar na macro a função `range().select`, mas sem sucesso.

Código utilizado:

```
Public Sub ExportarCSV()

Dim Arquivo As String

Arquivo = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
FileFilter:="Delimitado por vírgulas (*.csv), *.csv")

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Arquivo, xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenho guardada esta rotina, que grava um arquivo texto (que pode ser adaptada para salvar como CSV). A rotina salva para um arquivo texto os valores de um intervalo selecionado. Essa seleção pode ser manual, ou através de comando no VBA.

```
Private Sub fnSaveRangeAsText()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim lngStartRow As Long
    Dim lngStartColumn As Long
    Dim lngTotalRows As Long
    Dim lngTotalColumns As Long
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strLine As String

    lngStartRow = Selection.Row
    lngStartColumn = Selection.Column
    lngTotalRows = lngStartRow + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
    lngTotalColumns = lngStartColumn + Selection.Columns.Count - 1

    If Not TypeName(Selection) Like "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="NomeDoArquivoTexto" _
                , FileFilter:="TXT (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Salvar intervalo em arquivo TXT")
    If strFileName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Open strFileName For Output As #1
    For lngRow = lngStartRow To lngStartRow + lngTotalRows - 1
        For lngColumn = 1 To lngTotalColumns
            If Not IsNumeric(Selection.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn)) And Not IsDate(Selection.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn)) Then
                strLine = strLine & Chr(34) & Selection.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) & Chr(34)
            Else
                strLine = strLine & Selection.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn)
            End If
            strLine = strLine & IIf(lngColumn < lngTotalColumns, Chr(59), "")
        Next
        Print #1, strLine
        strLine = ""
    Next
    Close #1

End Sub
```